# Update the value from one adapter to another expandable listview in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am getting value from checking page adapter.If click the plus image in one list item the count value get increase.I want to update that particular value of child item in expandablelistview adapter.How to update that particular child value from checking page adapter.

**Checkinapadater:**

```
 @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {



            final Movie1 m = movieItems.get(position);


               if (m.getfood_totalprice() != null) {
                if (!m.getfood_totalprice().equals("null")) {
                    holder.amount.setText(m.getfood_totalprice());
                }
            }
            if (m.getfood_count() != null) {
                if (!m.getfood_count().equals("null")) {
                    holder.item_count.setText(m.getfood_count());
                }

            }


            holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int i = Integer.parseInt(holder.item_count.getText().toString());
                    if(i>=0){
                    int count = i + 1;

                    holder.item_count.setText(Integer.toString(count));

                    value = Integer.toString(count);

                }
            });

            holder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int i = Integer.parseInt(holder.item_count.getText().toString());
                    if(i>0){

                    int count = i - 1;
                    holder.item_count.setText(Integer.toString(count));

                }
                   });

        }
```

**Exapanadablelistapater:**

```
 @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Child child = (Child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        final Child modelChild = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems().get(childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.detail_list, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.minus = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minus);
            viewHolder.plus = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plus);
            viewHolder.green = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.green);
            viewHolder.red = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.red);
            viewHolder.item_count = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.count);
       //viewHolder.txtView  = (TextView) ((AppCompatActivity)context).findViewById(R.id.checked_item);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.tv.setText(child.getName());
        viewHolder.amount.setText(child.getPrice());


        viewHolder.item_count.setText(Integer.toString(child.getCount()));


        viewHolder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                    if(modelChild.getCount()>=0)  // set your count default 0 when you bind data initially
                    {


                        int count = (modelChild.getCount()) + 1;
                        modelChild.setCount(count);

                        int s= Integer.parseInt(Detailpage.item.getText().toString());

                        itemname.setText(Integer.toString(count1));
                        // viewHolder.txtView.setText(Integer.toString(count1)+"items");
                        count1=s+1;
                        Detailpage.item.setText(Integer.toString(count1));
                        int foodprice=0;
                        foodprice=Integer.parseInt(child.getPrice());

                        total1=child.getPrice();
                        value=Integer.toString(modelChild.getcount());
//
                        name = modelChild.getName();

                        id=child.getId();


                        new AsyncT().execute(user_id,res_id,id,name,total1,value);

                        groups.get(groupPosition).getItems().set(childPosition, modelChild);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

            }});


        viewHolder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                    if(modelChild.getCount()>0)  // set your count default 0 when you bind data initially
                    {   int count = modelChild.getCount() - 1;
                        modelChild.setCount(count);
                        int s= Integer.parseInt(Detailpage.item.getText().toString());
                        count1=s-1;
                        Detailpage.item.setText(Integer.toString(count1));

                         name=modelChild.getName();
//        

                        int foodprice=0;
                        foodprice=Integer.parseInt(child.getPrice());

                        int total = foodprice * child.getcount();
                        total1=child.getPrice();
//                         total1=Integer.toString(total);
                         value=Integer.toString(count);
                         id=child.getId();
                        if(count>0) {
                            new AsyncT().execute(user_id, res_id, id, name, total1, value);
                        }


                    }

                    modelChild.setChildName(modelChild.getChildName());
                    // set your other items if any like above
                    groups.get(groupPosition).getItems().set(childPosition, modelChild);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });





        return convertView;
    }
```

Movie1 model(checkin page):`

public class Movie1 {

```
public  String food_id,food_count,food_item,food_price,food_resid,food_totalprice;



public void setfood_id(String food_id) {
    this.food_id = food_id;
}

public void setfood_count(String food_count) {
    this.food_count = food_count;
}

public void setfood_price(String food_price) {
    this.food_price = food_price;
}

public void setfood_item(String food_item) {
    this.food_item = food_item;
}

public String getfood_item() {
    return food_item;
}

public String getfood_count() {
    return food_count;
}

public String getfood_price() {
    return food_price;
}

public void setfood_resid(String food_resid) {
    this.food_resid = food_resid;
}

public String getfood_resid() {
    return food_resid;
}

public String getfood_id() {
    return food_id;
}

public void setfood_totalprice(String food_totalprice) {
    this.food_totalprice = food_totalprice;
}

public String getfood_totalprice() {
    return food_totalprice;
}
```

}

`
Child model:(Expandable listview)

```
 public class Child {

    private String Name,childName,item_status,image1,available_from,available_to,price,id,status;
    private int Image,count;
    public Object getstatus;



    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return Image;
    }

    public void setImage(int Image) {
        this.Image = Image;
    }

    public void setcount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public int getcount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getChildName() {
        return childName;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setChildName(String childName) {
        this.childName = childName;
    }

    public void setItem_status(String item_status) {
        this.item_status = item_status;
    }

    public void setImage1(String image1) {
        this.image1 = image1;
    }

    public void setAvailable_to(String available_to) {
        this.available_to = available_to;
    }

    public void setAvailable_from(String available_from) {
        this.available_from = available_from;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getImage1() {
        return image1;
    }

    public String getItem_status() {
        return item_status;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setstatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public String getstatus() {
        return status;
    }



}
```

`[checkin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QY33k.png)

[Expandablelist adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvYLs.png)

Comment: @Nisarg can you help me if You know how to fix it

Comment: can you post image for better understanding ?

Comment: 1st image is for checkinpage and 2nd image expandablelistview @Nisarg

Comment: Use checking page arraylist for expandable listview adapter

Comment: How to use checking array list?Already 1 array list is created from json in expandable listview adapter

Comment: Use same arraylist for both adapter and use gson for saving arraylist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118411/discussion-between-abserve-tech-and-nisarg).